# How to see the settings of a Windows computer when the taskbar is inaccessible

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, taskbar, remote-connection

From my PC, there is a remote connection to a PC in another country. That PC has access towards a virtual computer, which is connected to via VMWare software. As that virtual machine is part of the remote network, I can't open it at my PC.

The problem is that the taskbar of that remote virtual PC is not visible in the VMWare window, and there seem to be problems with that virtual PC. So, I'd like to open the "settings viewer" application on that virtual PC, in order to start up the event viewer or to run some diagnostic tools.

I only have access to a command prompt and scheduled tasks (the latter is not important, I guess).

Does anybody know how I can open the settings on that PC, just using the command prompt?

Comment: I don't know what settings you're talking about. `taskmgr` would allow you to run the Task Manager. `eventvwr.msc` would allow you to start the Event Viewer. Is it a server? It might just not have the Desktop Experience installed, a windows version that is "GUI less" in a loose sense. Also check [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/192806).

Comment: CTRL + R > "control" for control panel?

Comment: You can open almost all of the control panel settings and other interesting programs from the command line. See [List of Run Commands in Windows 7 and 8](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/list-run-commands-windows-7-and-8). Without more information about exactly what settings you are trying to access we can't answer the question. Please [edit[ and be more explicit.

Comment: No need to go deeper into this question. I've added the URL from David Postill to my favorites, normally I'll be able to continue from there.
@DavidPostill, if you convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Dominique Answer added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'd like to open the "settings viewer" application from a `cmd` prompt

You can open almost all of the control panel settings and other interesting programs from the command line.

```
Function                                    Command
Open Documents Folder                       documents
Open Videos folder                          videos
Open Downloads Folder                       downloads
Open Favorites Folder                       favorites
Open Recent Folder                          recent
Open Recent Folder                          logoff
Open Pictures Folder                        pictures
Windows Sideshow                            control.exe /name Microsoft.WindowsSideshow
Windows CardSpace                           control.exe /name Microsoft.cardspace
Windows Anytime Upgrade                     WindowsAnytimeUpgradeui
Taskbar and Start Menu                      control.exe /name Microsoft.TaskbarandStartMenu
Troubleshooting                             control.exe /name Microsoft.Troubleshooting
User Accounts                               control.exe /name Microsoft.UserAccounts
Adding a new Device                         devicepairingwizard
Add Hardware Wizard                         hdwwiz
Advanced User Accounts                      netplwiz
Advanced User Accounts                      azman.msc
Backup and Restore                          sdclt
Bluetooth File Transfer                     fsquirt
Calculator                                  calc
Certificates                                certmgr.msc
Change Computer Performance Settings        systempropertiesperformance
Change Data Execution Prevention Settings   systempropertiesdataexecutionprevention
Change Data Execution Prevention Settings   printui
Character Map                               charmap
ClearType Tuner                             cttune
Color Management                            colorcpl
Command Prompt                              cmd
Component Services                          comexp.msc
Component Services                          dcomcnfg
Computer Management                         compmgmt.msc
Computer Management                         compmgmtlauncher
Connect to a Projector                      displayswitch
Control Panel                               control
Create A Shared Folder Wizard               shrpubw
Create a System Repair Disc                 recdisc
Credential Backup and Restore Wizard        credwiz
Data Execution Prevention                   systempropertiesdataexecutionprevention
Date and Time                               timedate.cpl
Default Location                            locationnotifications
Device Manager                              devmgmt.msc
Device Manager                              hdwwiz.cpl
Device Pairing Wizard                       devicepairingwizard
Diagnostics Troubleshooting Wizard          msdt
Digitizer Calibration Tool                  tabcal
DirectX Diagnostic Tool                     dxdiag
Disk Cleanup                                cleanmgr
Disk Defragmenter                           dfrgui
Disk Management                             diskmgmt.msc
Display                                     dpiscaling
Display Color Calibration                   dccw
Display Switch                              displayswitch
DPAPI Key Migration Wizard                  dpapimig
Driver Verifier Manager                     verifier
Ease of Access Center                       utilman
EFS Wizard                                  rekeywiz
Event Viewer                                eventvwr.msc
Fax Cover Page Editor                       fxscover
File Signature Verification                 sigverif
Font Viewer                                 fontview
Game Controllers                            joy.cpl
Getting Started                             gettingstarted
IExpress Wizard                             iexpress
Getting Started                             irprops.cpl
Install or Uninstall Display Languages      lusrmgr
Internet Explorer                           iexplore
Internet Options                            inetcpl.cpl
iSCSI Initiator Configuration Tool          iscsicpl
Language Pack Installer                     lpksetup
Local Group Policy Editor                   gpedit.msc
Local Security Policy                       secpol.msc
Local Users and Groups                      lusrmgr.msc
Location Activity                           locationnotifications
Magnifier                                   magnify
Malicious Software Removal Tool             mrt
Manage Your File Encryption Certificates    rekeywiz
Math Input Panel                            mip
Microsoft Management Console                mmc
Microsoft Support Diagnostic Tool           msdt
Mouse                                       main.cpl
NAP Client Configuration                    napclcfg.msc
Narrator                                    narrator
Network Connections                         ncpa.cpl
New Scan Wizard                             wiaacmgr
Notepad                                     notepad
ODBC Data Source Administrator              odbcad32
ODBC Driver Configuration                   odbcconf
On-Screen Keyboard                          osk
Paint                                       mspaint
Pen and Touch                               tabletpc.cpl
People Near Me                              collab.cpl
Performance Monitor                         perfmon.msc
Performance Options                         systempropertiesperformance
Phone and Modem                             telephon.cpl
Phone Dialer                                dialer
Power Options                               powercfg.cpl
Presentation Settings                       presentationsettings
Print Management                            printmanagement.msc
Printer Migration                           printbrmui
Printer User Interface                      printui
Private Character Editor                    eudcedit
Problem Steps Recorder                      psr
Programs and Features                       appwiz.cpl
Protected Content Migration                 dpapimig
Region and Language                         intl.cpl
Registry Editor                             regedit
Registry Editor 32                          regedt32
Remote Access Phonebook                     rasphone
Remote Desktop Connection                   mstsc
Resource Monitor                            resmon
Resultant Set of Policy                     rsop.msc
SAM Lock Tool                               syskey
Screen Resolution                           desk.cpl
Securing the Windows Account Database       syskey
Services                                    services.msc
Set Program Access and Computer Defaults    computerdefaults
Share Creation Wizard                       shrpubw
Shared Folders                              fsmgmt.msc
Snipping Tool                               snippingtool
Sound                                       mmsys.cpl
Sound recorder                              soundrecorder
SQL Server Client Network Utility           cliconfg
Sticky Notes                                stikynot
Stored User Names and Passwords             credwiz
Sync Center                                 mobsync
System Configuration                        msconfig
System Configuration Editor                 sysedit
System Information                          msinfo32
System Properties                           sysdm.cpl
System Properties   (Advanced Tab)          systempropertiesadvanced
System Properties (Computer Name Tab)       systempropertiescomputername
System Properties (Hardware Tab)            systempropertieshardware
System Properties (Remote Tab)              systempropertiesremote
System Properties (System Protection Tab)   systempropertiesprotection
System Restore                              rstrui
Task Manager                                taskmgr
Task Scheduler                              taskschd.msc
Trusted Platform Module (TPM) Management    tpm.msc
User Account Control Settings               useraccountcontrolsettings
Utility Manager                             utilman
Version Reporter Applet                     winver
Volume Mixer                                sndvol
Windows Action Center                       wscui.cpl
Windows Activation Client                   slui
Windows Anytime Upgrade Results             windowsanytimeupgraderesults
Windows CardSpace                           infocardcpl.cpl
Windows Disc Image Burning Tool             isoburn
Windows DVD Maker                           dvdmaker
Windows Easy Transfer                       migwiz
Windows Explorer                            explorer
Windows Fax and Scan                        wfs
Windows Features                            optionalfeatures
Windows Firewall                            firewall.cpl
Windows Firewall with Advanced Security     wf.msc
Windows Journal                             journal
Windows Media Player                        wmplayer
Windows Memory Diagnostic Scheduler         mdsched
Windows Mobility Center                     mblctr
Windows Picture Acquisition Wizard          wiaacmgr
Windows PowerShell                          powershell
Windows PowerShell ISE                      powershell_ise
Windows Remote Assistance                   msra
Windows Repair Disc                         recdisc
Windows Script Host                         wscript
Windows Update                              wuapp
Windows Update Standalone Installer         wusa
Windows Vesrion                             winver
WMI Management                              wmimgmt.msc
WordPad                                     write
XPS Viewer                                  xpsrchvw
```

Source [List of Run Commands in Windows 7 and 8](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/list-run-commands-windows-7-and-8)